# How to tag the log messages with a request header in golang using logrus?

Tags: logging, go

I am new to golang, and I need help attaching a http request header of my go application in all the log entries for a http request.The request is processed by multiple packages/go files. We use logrus package for logging. We have ton of code written already, so it would be nice to change something on a global level instead of going to each log entry.

In Java, we use slf4j, and we use a feature called MDC; and I am looking for something similar.

Comment: Would [`WithField`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus#Entry.WithField) method do the job?

Comment: I haven't found a way of using `WithField` for this purpose.

Comment: This answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41049394/4317945