# Golang Logging with Mapped Diagnostic Context

Tags: go, mdc

How can I achieve  [MDC Logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (Java) in GoLang?

I need to add UUIDs in all server logs  in order to be able to trace concurrent requests.

Comment: This helps: https://joeshaw.org/revisiting-context-and-http-handler-for-go-17/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java MDC relies on thread local storage, something Go does not have.

The closest thing is to thread a [Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) through your stack.

This is what more and more libraries are doing in Go.

A somewhat typical way is to do this via a middleware package that adds a request id to the context of a web request, like:

```
req = req.WithContext(context.WithValue(req.Context(),"requestId",ID))
```

Then, assuming you pass the context around, you pull it out with `ctx.Value("requestId")` and use it wherever it makes sense.

Possibly making your own custom logger function like:

```
func logStuff(ctx context.Context, msg string) {
    log.Println(ctx.Value("requestId"),msg) // call stdlib logger
}
```

There's a bunch of ways you may want to handle this, but that's a fairly simple form.

Comment: Go never ceases to amaze in the stupid design decisions that have all be solved in many other langauges and ecosystems

Comment: Sure, there are some places where one might say, hmm, weird.  I don't think this is one of them.   Threadlocals are a great source of bugs in languages that have them.  Folks use the as a crutch for poor application design and, especially in a RPC type system, often forget to clean values out, mixing data from one request to the next.

Comment: Don't use a string as the key. Use instead a value of a private type to avoid any conflict. `type requestIdKey struct{}`
`req = req.WithContext(context.WithValue(req.Context(),requestIdKey{},ID))`